# How to load a large .yml file to predict a face using python's opencv?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, performance, opencv, multiprocessing

I need to read a .yml file (1.06 Gb) for recognizing a face in the image but trainingData.yml is too large (3 to 4 minutes to load). How can I load this file to to increase the performance of my program?

I'm using this simple code to read that file:

```
self.recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
self.recognizer.read('recognizer/trainingData.yml')
```

I also tried to apply threading but no gain

```
for i in range(4):
    t=threading.Thread(target=self.recognizer.read('recognizer/trainingData.yml'))
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

Comment: Why 3 to 4 minutes is too long for you? Do you re-create the recognizer and re-load the training data each time you want to detect something?

Comment: each thread is reading the same data, the threading is probably slowing you down not speeding you up.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl actually yes I'm reloading the training data for each detection
Thanks for giving me hint :)